# Windows 7 Bootcamp not recognising devices

Tags: usb, bootcamp, windows

Has anybody encountered a problem with the USB driver when running Windows 7 on MacBook Pro 2010 (MC371)?

It doesn't recognize any USB drives or USB hard drives. I've tried both Windows Update and Bootcamp update - nothing helps. Where can I find a proper driver?

Comment: Strange, because it should use the Intel chipset drivers to run the USB. Have you updated to the latest Boot Camp?

Comment: yep, I've updated it inside windows to version 3.2 and have checked and updated windows itself, but it didn't help

Comment: I don't suppose you've tried calling Apple support? This seems like the kind of thing they might be able to help with...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Was this resolved?

Comment: nope, all the solution proposed didn't helped and I don't have any Apple Support in my country

Comment: Serge, try to update Win 7 along with Bootcamp within it. I've just done it and everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've got the solution. Yesterday I've updated both Win 7 and Windows Bootcamp, and the system found the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Windows 7 64-bit? If so, you might want to install the drivers in the Mac OS X DVD.

D:\Boot Camp\Drivers\Apple64.msi

Comment: I have no such path on my Mac OS DVD. Actually, there were some chipset drivers, I've tried all of them but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Uninstall the USB host drivers using device manager and then "Scan for hardware changes" to re-install them.

Might not work but its worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers that come with windows should work already. Bootcamp doesn't install any new driver USB-wise.

Most likely you got a bad windows installation. I would try the same disc on another machine just to be sure.

edit: Unless, of course, it's not an issue with the USB itself. [Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Tips-for-solving-problems-with-USB-devices)'s a good troubleshooting guide from microsoft. The only thing that it says about the USB itself is that it may be defective - even if it works on Mac. Hardware issues can be quite complex.

Comment: I'm sure installation is OK. A system from the same disk works fine on another machine

Comment: @NR4TR touche. I now suppose as well the USB works fine on OSX. If so, I'm out of ideas!

Comment: It does work fine :)

Comment: As @IntuitionHQ said, it may be a hardware issue and apple care would replace your mbp for you. Tried calling the support?

Comment: this is not a hardware issue. in mac os everything works fine. it's a windows driver issue, but i hardly can find any drivers.

Comment: @NR4TR that's the point. there is no driver. even the newest mbp still comes with USB 2.0. it's so basic and well established that both windows and mac comes with any driver needed built in. it's easier to have a mal function USB than "wrong drivers" for it. check out my edit.